# Add Textbox Line Loop

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code. I want to change CheckVar and do this in one Textbox, only the line be modified with I.

```
If TextBox3.Lines.contains(i)(word) Then
Else
TextBox3.Lines.contains(i)= tempTextBox.Text + " " + TxtbValAfterCompar.Text()
```

I want to change the way the code looks like, with textbox3.lines.

This is how the next code shows.

```
For Each word In words
         For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox2.Lines.Count - 1
             TxtbValBeforeCompar.Text = TextBox1.Lines(i)
             CompareNumbers()
             If TextBox1.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
                 found = True
                 Dim tempTextBox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckVar" & i.ToString), TextBox)
                 On Error Resume Next
                 If TextBox2.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
                     If tempTextBox.Text.Contains(word) Then
                     Else
                         tempTextBox.Text = tempTextBox.Text + " " + TxtbValAfterCompar.Text()
                     End If
                 Else
                 End If
             End If
         Next
     Next
```

Comment: Firstly, that first code snippet doesn't really make sense.  Try explaining what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than hoping we'll work it out from code that doesn't do it.  Secondly, the `Lines` property of a `TextBox` creates a new `String` array every time you access it so you should not be using that property over and over like that.  You should use the property once only and assign the result to a variable, then use that variable over and over.  If you make any changes to the array, you can assign it back to the `Lines` property when you're done.

Comment: Get rid of 'On Error Resume Next' Instead correct the code if this is an expected error or wrap in a 'Try...Catch...End Try` if it is unexpected. I don't see anything here that is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code but I have made a few comments that may help.

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
        Dim words() = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
        Dim found As Boolean
        For Each word In words
            'How about checking if the number of lines in TextBox1 is
            'equal to or more than the the number of lines in TextBox2.
            'If it is less than the code will fail with an index out of range error
            If TextBox1.Lines.Count < TextBox2.Lines.Count Then
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry TextBox1 does not have enough lines.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox2.Lines.Count - 1
                TxtbValBeforeCompar.Text = TextBox1.Lines(i)
                CompareNumbers()
                If TextBox1.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
                    found = True
                    'What is the point of tempTextBox? If is never visible and falls
                    'out of scope at the end of the Sub.
                    'Check that the number of CheckVars is not less than the number
                    'of lines in TextBox2
                    'REMEMBER The first value of i is 0 so you need a CheckVar0 TextBox
                    Dim counter As Integer
                    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
                        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("CheckVar") Then
                            counter += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                    'Of course you 
                    If counter < TextBox2.Lines.Count Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, not enough CheckVarX controls.")
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    'What is the point of tempTextBox? If is never visible and falls
                    'out of scope at the end of the Sub.
                    Dim tempTextBox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckVar" & i.ToString), TextBox)
                    'You could include the nested If in the outer If
                    'with AndAlso
                    If TextBox2.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
                        'Use the Not keyword an get rid of the empty If
                        If Not tempTextBox.Text.Contains(word) Then
                            tempTextBox.Text = tempTextBox.Text + " " + TxtbValAfterCompar.Text()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub CompareNumbers()
        'unknown code
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DoSomething()
    End Sub
```